# Multidimensional result array need to merge in single with same key value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have multidimensional result of an array need to merge in single array with same key value using PHP like below desired result.

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [POBI] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 3.9885520361991
                    [name] => POBI
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [POE] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 4
                    [name] => POE
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [LOS] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 4
                    [name] => LOS
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [Other Cop] => Array
                (
                )        

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [POBI] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 4
                    [name] => POBI
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [POE] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 3.9
                    [name] => POE
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [LOS] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 4
                    [name] => LOS
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [Other Cop] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 2
                    [name] => OC
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )       

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [POBI] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 7
                    [name] => POBI
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [POE] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 3.0
                    [name] => POE
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [LOS] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 4
                    [name] => LOS
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [Other Cop] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 1.8
                    [name] => OC
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )
        )



)
```

**Desired Result**

```
Array
(
        [POBI] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 3.9885520361991
                    [name] => POBI
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 4
                    [name] => POBI
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 7
                    [name] => POBI
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )    

        )

        [POE] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 4
                    [name] => POE
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 3.9
                    [name] => POE
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 3.0
                    [name] => POE
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )    

        )

        [LOS] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 4
                    [name] => LOS
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 4
                    [name] => LOS
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 4
                    [name] => LOS
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )    

        )

        [Other Cop] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 2
                    [name] => OC
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [average] => 1.8
                    [name] => OC
                    [year] => 2014-2015
                )    

        )
)
```

My current implementation attempts to do something like this:

```
foreach($data as $k => $v) {
    $results[$k] = array_column($arr, $k);
}
print_r($results);
```

Comment: may be this will work: `$results[$k][] = array_column($arr, $k);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$return = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $innerKey => $innerValue) {
        if (!isset($return[$innerKey])) {
            $return[$innerKey] = [];
        }
        $return[$innerKey][] = $innerValue;
    }
}

var_dump($return);
die();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution to your problem. A one liner actually.

```
$mergedArray = array_merge_recursive($arrayOne, $arrayTwo);

// In your case
$merged = array_merge_recursive($array[0], $array[1]);
```

Hope this will do the trick.

#### Edit

As suggested by Brad Kent, if you have more than two values that need to be merged:

```
$merged = call_use_func_array('array_merge_recursive', array_values($array));
```

Comment: probably something more like `$merged = call_use_func_array('array_merge_recursive', array_values($array));`   (can't assume there are only two two "sub-arrays" that need merged)

Comment: I have result set of array not individual sub arrray

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($yourArrayName as $items)
{
    foreach ($items as $id => $item) {
        $result[$id][] = $item;     
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

NOTE: Your sample result data has duplicate index for 1 by the way... Should be typo I guess. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

you're close.
try

```
$keys = array_keys($data[0]);
$results = array();
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $results[$key] = array_column($data, $key);
}
```

this assumes each group has the same keys.